# Set content of Jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm doing a node.js server and i pretend to use it do generate and send the HTML pages of my webpage to the client.

i pretend to generate the html file with information that i get from the database.

is it possible to use JADE to create the template of the page and to change specific pieces of the file with that information?

For exemple, i have the page of users' information. I want to have a template and write the information in specific places.

How can i do it?

Comment: Have you searched official jade lang site?

Comment: @u_mulder problem is that template inheritance doesn't exist on the website, you can find it only on the github repo in the root directory of the source at this file: **jade-language.md**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade-language.md#template-inheritance

base.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    block title
      title Foobar
  body
    block content
```

page.jade

```
extends page
block title
  title Qux
block content
  Lorem ipsum
```

You can also prepend and append to blocks, so it won't overwrite the block.